# UFW: can't connect to SSH with "to 127.0.0.1" option

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, ubuntu-14.04, ufw

i tried to restrict the SSH connectivity to a subnet and wanted to set the "to" part to localhost.
(Server will be routing over bridge device to virtual servers, and i wanted do drop ssh connections to the Virtual Servers on the main server.)

This is the code i've tried:

```
ufw logging on
ufw allow proto tcp from 148.7.0.0/16 to 127.0.0.1 port 22
ufw default deny 
ufw enable
```

Wich locks me out of the server, i can't connect anymore. If i change the to part to: "to any" it's working again.

The Server I'm speaking of is a root server hosted by hetzner.

Thx in advance for any explanation on this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `127.0.0.1` as destination. It's the loopback address, and can be only accessed by programs running on your own computer.

To permit access to SSH on your server, you can just add a rule to allow access to all IP addresses registered on your server:

```
ufw allow from 148.7.0.0/16 to any port 22 proto tcp
```

In this case, `any` is *any IP address on your server*.

Comment: Thx for the Answer.
In Order to Block all routed ssh connection attemps to the virtual server which are connected through a bridge device - i just substitute 127.0.0.1 with the Servers IP Adress.